# Получение директории программы

Tags: .net

Всем доброго времени суток.

Задача - получить адрес установленной программы (браузера), допустим, нам нужно поднять operу, нужно получить адрес к ней.

Так как держать `@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\opera.exe"` не есть гуд.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В дополнение к предыдущему ответу. GUID программы вряд ли будет известен заранее (а в некторых случаях это вовсе и не GUID), поэтому есть смысл поискать программу в этом разделе реестра по её названию (параметр '**DisplayName**'). А интересующий вас параметр - это '**InstallLocation**'.

```
public static string GetLocation(string programName)
{
    var uninstall = Registry.LocalMachine
        .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");

    if (uninstall == null)
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }

    foreach (string subKeyName in uninstall.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        using (var subKey = uninstall.OpenSubKey(subKeyName))
        {
            if (subKey != null)
            {
                var keyValue = subKey.GetValue("DisplayName");
                if (keyValue != null && keyValue.ToString() == programName)
                    return subKey.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    return String.Empty;
}
```

И сразу же хочу сделать 2 замечания к этому коду:

1. Сравнивать название программы в большинстве случаев не будет имет смысла, потому что в название обычно входит и версия. Скорее всего сравнение лучше заменить на [String.StartsWith()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.startswith.aspx).
2. В 64-битной системе информация о всех программах, которые работают в [WoW64](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WOW64)-режиме будет находится в другом разделе HKLM:

> SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Поэтому в 64-битной системе есть смысл проверить два этих раздела.

Comment: благодарю вас

Answer (score 3):

Универсально и хоть с какой-то гарантией - спросить у юзера :-)
Если не универсально и без гарантии, то можно поискать где-то тут:

```
HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall/{что-то}/InstallLocation
```

P.S. {что-то} - это GUID программы, который нужно знать заранее.

P.P.S. Или аналогично - в HKCU

Comment: спасибо вам)